# Tensorflow Module Not Found Error when running MNIST TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tpu

I'm new to tensorflow and was trying to follow the tutorial here https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart to run the MNIST TPU model.

I got error from

```
  python3 mnist_main.py \
  --tpu=$TPU_NAME \
  --model_dir=$MODEL_DIR \
  --data_dir=$DATA_DIR \
  --train_epochs=10 \
  --distribution_strategy=tpu \
  --download
```

Error message

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_main.py", line 31, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification.resnet import common
  File "/usr/share/models/official/vision/image_classification/resnet/common.py", line 26, in <module>
    import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_model_optimization'
```

Any idea about to solve it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install it using command line (or terminal).

```
pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow-model-optimization
```

Comment: I'm using Linux, it seems pip doesn't work on linix. Sorry I should specify my OS

Comment: sudo apt-get install pip

Comment: Here is the real skill you need to learn and it's one that can solve the majority of errors you encounter. From the two issues you just had, it would indicate you need to Google your issues first and if you did, learn how to use Google more effectively. Pip is available on Linux. If you get a message like pip not found, your first instinct should be to Google "how to install pip" or even "pip not found" and you'll find the answer. This is not meant to be condescending. I want to help you problem solve more efficiently.

Comment: I am facing this issue in colab of all places !! The package is installed in my system, I have used it for other stuff, but I had to use "experimental" layers with a new model, which jupyter is not agreeing with so I moved over to colab, and other stuff worked but now I have "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_model_optimization" from colab. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Colab, if you are running a notebook using qkeras you need to do the following:

```
!git clone https://github.com/google/qkeras.git 
import sys 
sys.path.append('qkeras') 
!pip install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner.git 
!pip install tensorflow_model_optimization 
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
```